# JavaScript: a small new beginner question about empty array, adding function argument to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am kind of struggling the question and what to do here so I wish to seek help to solve this:

- Create an empty array.
- Create a function that accepts one argument.
- Inside the function, add the argument to the array.
- Call the function and pass in a value of any type.*

So I know empty Array is:

```
const emptyArray = []
```

Function with 1 argument would be:

```
function oneArgument(argument) {}
```

"Inside the function, add the argument to the array." is what I seem to struggle with, what does the task mean?

and at the end I guess I will just give value to `oneArgument(someValue)`

Would apprechiate the help :)

Comment: To add an element at the end of an array, you usually use push:  `emptyArray.push(argument)`. On a side note, naming your array `emptyArray` can be a little misleading, because it's not empty anymore, once you insert elements into it

Comment: "Inside the function" refers to the *function body* - this is code which goes inside of `{}`. For example, if you wanted a function that logged the result of some argument plus two, you would say `function logArgPlusTwo(arg) { console.log(arg + 2); }`. You don't want to "log arg plus two"; you want to "add argument to array". I leave the rest to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create an empty array, so that we could store values. What happens next is we make a function, that takes in a single argument `number`. We add it to our array and call the function.

We use arguments for functions. This allows us to have reusable functions. We might use the same function all over our application passing different type of number. Maybe in one file we might pass number `500`, maybe in another file we need a negative number. Whole idea behind this, is that we make it resuable. The function doesnt care what type of number we pass, it will act the same way every time we call it, but with different number or any other value. Argument means that, function expects a value and this value can differ every single time we call the function.

Hope this helps.

```
const numbers = [];

function updateNumbersList (number) {
  numbers.push(number)
} 

updateNumbersList(1)

console.log(numbers)
```